# Htaccess rewrite rule redirected but server not processh

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want my server to read this page `example.com/myapp.php?p=11` against the URL `example.com/myapp/my-technical-effort`.

I have tried this `.htaccess` rule:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase / 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/myapp\.php$ 
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^p=11 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ example.com/myapp/my-technical-effort [QSD,R=301,L]
```

it redirects to the new URL but the server says "page not found" on this server with 404 error.

Can you please help me to rewrite the rule so the server can serve the page `example.com/myapp.php?p=11` against the URL `example.com/myapp/my-technical-effort`.

My current `.htaccess` is as follows:

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
  Header always append X-Frame-Options ALLOWALL
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]
  Header always set Content-Security-Policy "upgrade-insecure-requests;"
</IfModule>
```

Anyone can help me please?

Answer (score 1):

Your implementation is the wrong way round. Have a try that way:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?myapp/my-technical-effort$ /myapp.php?p=11 [QSD,L]
```

You need to implement your rewrite rules based on actual imcoming requests. Those should get rewritten internally, so those have to be matched.

This asumes that the actual request you want to rewrite is to `/myapp/my-technical-effort` (your question is a bit vague in that), and that `/myapp.php?p=11` is the internal resource you want to get queried.

---

UPDATE:

Your comment below suggests that you are actually looking for a solution to redirect the "old" URL to the new one. It is indeed possible to combine that with above rewriting:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^p=11$
RewriteRule ^/myapp\.php$ /myapp/my-technical-effort [QSD,R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^/?myapp/my-technical-effort$ /myapp.php?p=11 [QSD,L]
```

This will *redirect* any client that requests the "old" url (`https://example.com/myapp.php?p=11`) to the "new" url (`https://example.com/`/myapp/my-technical-effort). And it will internally rewrite incoming requests to the "new" url to the actual script able to respond to the requests (`/myapp.php`).

Comment: The `QSD` flag causes no harm, but is superfluous here.

Comment: Hi,
Thanks for the reply, your solution gives error. https://htaccess.madewithlove.com?share=8cd30692-d65d-4150-8361-e74dc6311f4e The problem is that my url is working as example.com/myapp.php?p=11 and I want rewrite and it should be some thing like this example.com/myapp/my-technical-effort means I want to convert query sting to clean url. Can you please help with this?

Comment: Well, the rule in the test you linked here in the comment is because you added a condition that does not make sense. The code you tested there will _never_ match.

Comment: I added an update to the question: an additional external redirection. I hope that is what you actually ask.